# When does the callback function inside the useCallback() hook runs exactly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code for infinite scroll load

Mainly two components MainComponent and a custom hook component
everytime i entered something on search item it sends the request and display the data to screen and inside main component i am using lastELementRef to set observer Api on that to send the request again when i scrolled at the end .

Not able to understand when does function passed inside useCallBack(()=>{}) runs
to check how many times it runs i did console.log at line no 21 inside MainComponent.

It will be very nice of folks on this community if anybody can explain me when does it runs.

I have googled and watched some Youtube videos on useCallback and all I can come up with is that it gives the function object only when the dependency inside its dependency array changes else on it memoizes the function on each re-render if dependency does not change.?
i am sharing the code here

have used axios to send request.

```js
//MainComponent
import React,{useState,useRef,useCallback} from 'react'
import useBookSearch from './useBookSearch';

export default function MainComponent() {
    
    //these 2 stataes are here because 
    //we want them to be used in this component only
    //meaning we dont want them to be part 
    //of any custom logic 

    const[query,setQuery] = useState('');
    const[pageNumber,setPageNumber] = useState(1);
    const observer = useRef();
     

    const  {books,loading,hasMore,error} = useBookSearch(query,pageNumber);
    
     
    const lastElementRef = useCallback(node=>{

        console.log("How many times did i run ?");

        if(loading) return ;

        if(observer.current) observer.current.disconnect();
        observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries=>{
          if(entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore){
              setPageNumber(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
          }

        })
        if(node) observer.current.observe(node);
        console.log(node);
    },[loading,hasMore])


    const handleSearch=(e)=>{

      setQuery(e.target.value);
      setPageNumber(1);

    }

  

    return (
        <div>

            <input  value={query} type="text" onChange={handleSearch} ></input>
            {books.map((book,index) =>{
                if(books.length === index + 1)
                {
                return <div ref={lastElementRef}key={book}>{book}</div>

                }
                else{
                  return <div key={book}>{book}</div>  
                }
            })}
            {loading && 'Loading.....................'}
            {error && 'Error........'}
            

        </div>
    )
}
```

//custom hook component-useBookSearch

```
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
export default function useBookSearch(query,pageNumber) {
    const[loading,setLoading] = useState('true');
    const[error,setError] = useState('false');
    const[books,setBooks] = useState([]);
    const[hasMore,setHasMore] = useState(false);

    //second useEffect which clear the books first 
    //and then make an api request

    useEffect(()=>{
      setBooks([]);
    },[query])

    useEffect(()=>{
        setLoading(true);
        setError(false);
        let cancel ;
       axios({
           method:'GET',
           url:'http://openlibrary.org/search.json',
           params:{q:query,page:pageNumber},
           cancelToken:new axios.CancelToken(c=>cancel=c)
       }).then(res=>{
           setBooks(prevBooks=>{
               return [...new Set([...prevBooks,...res.data.docs.map(b=>b.title)])]
           })
           setHasMore(res.data.docs.length > 0);
           setLoading(false);
           console.log(res.data);
       }).catch(e=>{

            if(axios.isCancel(e)) return
            setError(true); 
         })

       return ()=> cancel();
    },[query,pageNumber])  
    return {loading,error,books,hasMore};
}
```

screenshot of how the code looks when i entered the string test to fetch data

Screenshot of the console window when entering test into input box

[image]

Comment: It creates and returns a new function whenever your dependencies (`[loading,hasMore]`) change. You decide when to call the function

Comment: i am passing it down inside input as ref={lastELementRef} is that calling it and why does it print 5 times on console.log()

Comment: It runs when you call it.

Comment: plz can u tell me in this current case when it is being called as i am not explicitly doing lastRefElement() ?